# Diagrama de classes a partir de classes já criadas não aparece o relacionamento

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Quando eu crio um diagrama de classes no VS2017 a partir de classes já existentes, a ligação de relacionamento não aparece.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
namespace CloudEye.Domain
{
   public class Car
   {
      public CarPlate CarPlate { get; private set; }
      public double Capacity { get; set; }
      public double Consumption { get; private set; }
      public double Autonomy => Capacity * Consumption;

      protected Car () { }

      public Car(CarPlate carPlate, double capacity, double consumption)
      {
         CarPlate = carPlate;
         Capacity = capacity;
         Consumption = consumption;
      }
  }
}

namespace CloudEye.Domain
{
   public class CarPlate
   {
      public string Characters { get; private set; }

      protected CarPlate() { }

      public CarPlate(string characters)
      {
         Characters = characters;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Você diz Herança? porque no seu código tem um agregação!

Comment: Não herança, agregação mesmo. No diagrama deveria haver uma linha ligando a classe **CarPlate** à propriedade _CarPlate_ da classe CAR.

Comment: não... a linha só aparece quando há herança... é um diagrama de classes...não um modelo ER

Comment: Na verdade a relação é de composição. Em UML existe símbolos para agregação, composição, associação simples, dentre outros.
[Exemplo](http://www.cleibsonalmeida.blog.br/site/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/uml_composicao.gif)
Mas o visual studio aparentemente não consegue identificar a relação entre as classes.

Comment: O VS até tem as ligações de relacionamento, como mostra a [imagem](https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/MSDNBlogsFS/prod.evol.blogs.msdn.com/CommunityServer.Blogs.Components.WeblogFiles/00/00/00/30/15/metablogapi/2781.image_01E98EB4.png)

O problema é que ele não está conseguindo fazer a "Engenharia Reversa", ou seja, montar o diagrama com base nas classes já existentes.